# How to implement mqtt with SSL/TLS certs in Go?

Tags: go, ssl, mqtt

I'm trying to make a script in Go that will send a message to a mqtt broker with SSL / TLS certificates. I created these certificates with openSSL and tested mqtt communication with mosquitto_sub and mosquitto_pub commands and this works fine, but when I try to send a message with the Go script I get the following error:

**network Error : read tcp 192.168.1.243:59454->192.168.1.171:8883: read: connection reset by peer**

And in the log of the mosquitto broker, the following message appears:

**1627682906: New connection from 192.168.1.243 on port 8883.

1627682906: OpenSSL Error: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

1627682906: Socket error on client , disconnecting.

1627682906: New connection from 192.168.1.243 on port 8883.

1627682906: OpenSSL Error: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

1627682906: Socket error on client , disconnecting.**

The code I'm using is the following:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"

    MQTT "github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang" // mqtt
)

func main() {
    broker := "192.168.1.171"
    port := "8883"
    topic := "sensor/temperature"

    opts := MQTT.NewClientOptions()
    opts.AddBroker(fmt.Sprintf("tcp://%s:%s", broker, port))
    opts.SetClientID("Device")
    opts.SetUsername("")
    opts.SetPassword("")
    tlsConfig := NewTlsConfig()
    opts.SetTLSConfig(tlsConfig)

    client := MQTT.NewClient(opts)
    if token := client.Connect(); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
        log.Println("1. ", token.Error())
    }

    token := client.Publish(topic, 0, false, "36.2")
    token.Wait()

    client.Disconnect(250)
}

func NewTlsConfig() *tls.Config {
    certpool := x509.NewCertPool()
    ca, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/home/pi/server.crt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err.Error())
    }
    certpool.AppendCertsFromPEM(ca)
    return &tls.Config{
        RootCAs: certpool,
    }
}
```

Am I have any bugs in the code or is there some other way to implement mqtt communication with SSL certificates in Go?

Comment: here you have an example https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang/blob/master/fvt_client_test.go#L72

Answer (score 2):

The first issue I noticed is (this may be the only issue or there may be others):

`opts.AddBroker(fmt.Sprintf("tcp://%s:%s", broker, port))`

Using the url scheme `tcp` (or `mqtt`) indicates that you wish to establish an unencrypted connection (the certificate you provide will be ignored). To request MQTT over TLS use one of `ssl`, `tls`, `mqtts`, `mqtt+ssl` or `tcps`. For example [the demo](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang/blob/master/cmd/ssl/main.go#L107) (which I suspect your code is based on) uses:

`opts.AddBroker("ssl://iot.eclipse.org:8883")`